# Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : infinite or missing values in 'x' (checked no negative values exist)

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca

I know this is a common error for PCA but I went through the solutions provided and its not working.

I followed:
[Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : 0 extent dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352815/error-in-svdx-nu-0-0-extent-dimensions)

Below is my code extract:

```
require(class)
set.seed(2095)
# dataset source:https://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup99.html
normalize<-function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}
dataset <- read.csv("data/kdd_data_10pc.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
names   <- read.csv("data/kdd_names.csv", header = FALSE , sep = ";")
names(dataset) <- sapply((1:nrow(names)),function(i) toString(names[i, 1]))

# extracting relevant features
dataset_extracted <- dataset[, c("src_bytes", "dest_bytes", "count", "dst_host_count", "dst_host_same_srv_rate", "dst_host_serror_rate", "label")]

head(dataset_extracted, 3)

log.kdd   <-log(dataset_extracted[, 1:6])
kdd.label <- dataset_extracted[, 7]

kdd.pca <-prcomp(log.kdd,
             center = TRUE,
             scale. = TRUE)
```

Summary(dataset) output is as follow:

```
 summary(dataset_extracted)
   src_bytes           dest_bytes          count       dst_host_count  dst_host_same_srv_rate dst_host_serror_rate      label       
 Min.   :        0   Min.   :      0   Min.   :  0.0   Min.   :  0.0   Min.   :0.0000         Min.   :0.0000       smurf.  :280790  
 1st Qu.:       45   1st Qu.:      0   1st Qu.:117.0   1st Qu.:255.0   1st Qu.:0.4100         1st Qu.:0.0000       neptune.:107201  
 Median :      520   Median :      0   Median :510.0   Median :255.0   Median :1.0000         Median :0.0000       normal. : 97278  
 Mean   :     3026   Mean   :    869   Mean   :332.3   Mean   :232.5   Mean   :0.7538         Mean   :0.1768       back.   :  2203  
 3rd Qu.:     1032   3rd Qu.:      0   3rd Qu.:511.0   3rd Qu.:255.0   3rd Qu.:1.0000         3rd Qu.:0.0000       satan.  :  1589  
 Max.   :693375640   Max.   :5155468   Max.   :511.0   Max.   :255.0   Max.   :1.0000         Max.   :1.0000       ipsweep.:  1247  
                                                                                                                   (Other) :  3713
```

Based on the summary none of the extracted columns minimum value are of any negative value.

I'm new to machine learning. Appreciate any help provided. The exact error shown was

```
Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi its extremely lengthy the results... i dun tink its feasible to include here.. i also corrected some typo in my code. reference website was https://www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/

Comment: i added the error displayed in my question

Comment: It may be because some of your variables have a variance of zero. You can check this with `apply(x, 2, var) == 0` or similar.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707215/calculate-svd-in-r-error-missing-or-infinite-values?rq=1) the same problem and solution?

Comment: @Joe not sure if its the same as there wasnt exactly a solution provided...

Answer (score 1):

You apply a log transformation to an object (`dataset`) containing zero values. This will produce elements of negative infinity. Try using `log1p()` instead.

Also don't forget to apply the standardisation you encode in the function `normalize()`.

Also also, given the magnitude of some of the outliers, I'm not sure a log transformation will be sufficient - you may need to consider excluding some observations.